# How is ORDER BY of chars in MSSQL working in this example?

Tags: sql, sql-server, char

I am trying to grasp how the order by is working. In the book SQL Heads down the author mentions that Uppercase letters should show up "before" lowercase characters whilst selecting and ordering them.

Why dont the letters show up in the order:
*AaBbCcDd* instead of *AabBCcdD*?

Worth noting is that the author gives examples in MySQL and I am using MSSQL.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that the order of the characters is following ASCII. But i do not understand why first are the special chars.

Comment: @Svenwas3f - only a few collations in SQL Server (notably, the binary ones) will use ASCII ordering specifically.

Comment: Also worth noting is that any educational material will generally be specific (directly or implicitly) to the database engine on which it is based. Do NOT get in the habit of assuming that SQL which is written and tested for one engine works (correctly or exactly the same) for a different engine.

Comment: And another note - be careful who/what you read. You don't provide any context so we can't know what the topic was for this statement. But rows in a table or a resultset have no "natural" order. If the statement that generates a resultset has no order by clause, the resultset has no specific order and the engine returns them in an undefined order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the [collation order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15) in your database: it looks like the current one simply treats upper and lower case versions of the same character as indistinguishable, so they will end up in any which order.

This is what makes developing systems for non-English usages such a lovely task: few Western European languages agree on the proper way of alphabetizing! As everybody knows, ÅÄÖ come last, whereas V and W are indistinguishable when sorting...

Answer (score 1):

> In the book SQL Heads down the author mentions that Uppercase letters should show up "before" lowercase characters whilst selecting and ordering them.

This statement is only partially correct at best, and in truth wrong. What order the characters are "sorted" in is all to do with the collation the value is in and also how it treats those values when they are equal. Take the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, --Gives the RDBMS something else it is likely to ORDER BY, but NOT guarenteed
                            Insensitive char(1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI,
                            CaseSensitive AS Insensitive COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI,
                            AccentSensitive AS Insensitive COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
                            CaseAndAccentSensitive AS Insensitive COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,
                            BinaryCollation AS Insensitive COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,
                            SQLLatin AS Insensitive COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI);

GO


INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable
VALUES('a'),('A'),('b'),('B'),('C'),('c'),('D'),('d'),('e'),('E');
GO

SELECT ID,Insensitive
FROM dbo.SomeTable
ORDER BY Insensitive;
GO

SELECT ID,CaseSensitive
FROM dbo.SomeTable
ORDER BY CaseSensitive;
GO

SELECT ID,AccentSensitive
FROM dbo.SomeTable
ORDER BY AccentSensitive;
GO

SELECT ID,CaseAndAccentSensitive
FROM dbo.SomeTable
ORDER BY CaseAndAccentSensitive;
GO

SELECT ID,BinaryCollation
FROM dbo.SomeTable
ORDER BY BinaryCollation;
GO

SELECT ID,SQLLatin
FROM dbo.SomeTable
ORDER BY SQLLatin;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```

In the above, we get several different orders. For the first, ordering by `Insensitive` using the collation `Latin1_General_CI_AI` we get an order similar to you. I've included the `ID` in the `SELECT`, as this will likely mean that for such a small data set the data is returned in the order of the `CLUSTERED INDEX`.

For the next, `Latin1_General_CS_AI`, the data is returned in the order of lowercase, then Upper Case. `Latin1_General_CI_AS` returns in the same order as `Insensitive` and `CaseAndAccentSensitive` in the same order as `Latin1_General_CS_AI`.

Then we have binary collations. For the one I chose, `Latin1_General_BIN`, the order is **all** Uppercase characters first, followed by **all** lowercase characters.

Then, finally, we have `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`, which *does* follow your expectation of Uppercase then lowercase.